# How to get Locale from its String representation in Java?

Tags: java, locale

Is there a neat way of getting a [Locale](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) instance from its "programmatic name" as returned by Locale's `toString()` method? An obvious and ugly solution would be parsing the String and then constructing a new Locale instance according to that, but maybe there's a better way / ready solution for that?

The need is that I want to store some locale specific settings in a SQL database, including Locales themselves, but it would be ugly to put serialized Locale objects there. I would rather store their String representations, which seem to be quite adequate in detail.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See the `Locale.getLanguage()`, `Locale.getCountry()`... Store this combination in the database instead of the `"programatic name"`...
When you want to build the Locale back, use `public Locale(String language, String country)`

Here is a sample code :)

```
// May contain simple syntax error, I don't have java right now to test..
// but this is a bigger picture for your algo...
public String localeToString(Locale l) {
    return l.getLanguage() + "," + l.getCountry();
}

public Locale stringToLocale(String s) {
    StringTokenizer tempStringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
    if(tempStringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    String l = tempStringTokenizer.nextElement();
    if(tempStringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    String c = tempStringTokenizer.nextElement();
    return new Locale(l,c);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @raj why to use tokenizer , If Java gives you ready methods? e.g toLocale(String str). Please see examples in answer

Comment: You should be using Locale.forLanguageTag(String)

Answer (score 156):

Method that returns locale from string exists in commons-lang library:
`LocaleUtils.toLocale(localeAsString)`

Comment: LocaleUtils.toLocale doesn't support strings like 'zh-Hans', 'pt-PT', etc.

Comment: If you have an hyphen `-` between locale parts you are dealing with an IETF BCP 47 tag, if you are using Java 7 you can use `Locale.forLanguageTag`

Answer (score 80):

Since Java 7 there is factory method `Locale.forLanguageTag` and instance method `Locale.toLanguageTag` using [IETF language tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag).

Comment: Just want to emphasize that `Locale.forLanguageTag` works IETF locale strings (ie `en-US`) and does not work with ISO locale strings (ie `en_US`)

Answer (score 50):

1. Java provides lot of things with proper implementation lot of complexity can be avoided. This returns **ms_MY**.

   ```
   String key = "ms-MY";
   Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag(key).build();
   ```
2. Apache Commons has `LocaleUtils` to help parse a string representation. This will return **en_US**

   ```
   String str = "en-US";
   Locale locale =  LocaleUtils.toLocale(str);
   System.out.println(locale.toString());
   ```
3. You can also use locale constructors.

   ```
   // Construct a locale from a language code.(eg: en)
   new Locale(String language)
   // Construct a locale from language and country.(eg: en and US)
   new Locale(String language, String country)
   // Construct a locale from language, country and variant.
   new Locale(String language, String country, String variant)
   ```

Please check this [LocaleUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/LocaleUtils.html#toLocale(java.lang.String)) and this [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to explore more methods.

Comment: LocaleUtils.toLocale(localeStringRepresentation)  does the job neatly. Also if you see the implementation of this method, it is quite comprehensive!

Comment: org.apache.commons.lang3.LocaleUtils.toLocale will throw an exception if it receives "en-US".

From the docs:
This method validates the input strictly. The language code must be lowercase. The country code must be uppercase. The separator must be an underscore. The length must be correct.

Answer (score 24):

**Option 1 :**

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.LocaleUtils.toLocale("en_US")
```

**Option 2 :**

```
Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US")
```

Please note **Option 1** is "underscore" between language and country , and **Option 2** is "dash".

Comment: Call requires API level 21 (current min is 17): java.util.Locale#forLanguageTag

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Spring framework in your project you can also use:

```
org.springframework.util.StringUtils.parseLocaleString("en_US");
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StringUtils.html#parseLocaleString-java.lang.String-):

> Parse the given String representation into a Locale

Comment: The docs on this say it's specifically the inverse of `Locale#toString()` - perfect! :)

Answer (score 12):

This answer may be a little late, but it turns out that parsing out the string is not as ugly as the OP assumed. I found it quite simple and concise:

```
public static Locale fromString(String locale) {
    String parts[] = locale.split("_", -1);
    if (parts.length == 1) return new Locale(parts[0]);
    else if (parts.length == 2
            || (parts.length == 3 && parts[2].startsWith("#")))
        return new Locale(parts[0], parts[1]);
    else return new Locale(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
}
```

I tested this (on Java 7) with all the examples given in the Locale.toString() documentation: "en", "de_DE", "_GB", "en_US_WIN", "de__POSIX", "zh_CN_#Hans", "zh_TW_#Hant-x-java", and "th_TH_TH_#u-nu-thai".

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**: This is not recommended for use in Java 7+ according to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

> In particular, clients who parse the output of toString into language, country, and variant fields can continue to do so (although this is **strongly discouraged**), although the variant field will have additional information in it if script or extensions are present.

Use Locale.forLanguageTag and Locale.toLanguageTag instead, or if you must, Locale.Builder.

Comment: Java 7 `Locale.forLanguageTag` applies only for language tags encoded as indicated in IETF's BCP 47, with an hyphen (`-`), not an underscore (`_`) as in the return of `Locale`'s `toString` method

Comment: You're right. There still needs to be some way to convert the existing Locale representations to BCP47 format. My intention was to suggest that going forward, `Locale`s should not be stored in their `toString` form, but in their `toLanguageTag` form, which is convertible back to a `Locale` more easily and accurately.

Comment: Wouldn't this method have a number of edge cases that could cause index out of bounds?

Comment: @user2524908: I don't think so, as he is always testing the array length before accessing its elements. The solution might have many edge cases where it does not work properly, but not "index out of bounds"

Answer (score 8):

Old question with plenty of answers, but here's more solutions:

- [Get Locale From String](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/GetLocaleFromString.htm)
- [Converts a String to a Locale](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ConvertsaStringtoaLocale.htm)

Comment: The java2s example is pretty good and also includes the variant handling

Answer (score 4):

Might be late but if someone looking for simple solution:

Instead of `toString()` set Locale string by using: `String langTag = localeObj.toLanguageTag();`

Store `langTag` in DB or wherever you want

At the consumer side get `String lanTag = fromDB(); // or wherever`

Get the Locale by: `Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(langTag);`

No additional dependency needed!

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a static `valueOf` method for this, which is a bit surprising.

One rather ugly, but simple, way, would be to iterate over `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`, comparing their `toString` values with your value.

Not very nice, but no string parsing required. You could pre-populate a `Map` of Strings to Locales, and look up your database string in that Map.

Comment: Ah, the iteration might be quite a reasonable solution. Indeed it's surprising that Locale doens't have a static method for this.

Comment: The predifned `Locale` instances represent a very smal subset of valid locales only. It's by no means complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this on Android. Works fine for me.

```
private static final Pattern localeMatcher = Pattern.compile
        ("^([^_]*)(_([^_]*)(_#(.*))?)?$");

public static Locale parseLocale(String value) {
    Matcher matcher = localeMatcher.matcher(value.replace('-', '_'));
    return matcher.find()
            ? TextUtils.isEmpty(matcher.group(5))
                ? TextUtils.isEmpty(matcher.group(3))
                    ? TextUtils.isEmpty(matcher.group(1))
                        ? null
                        : new Locale(matcher.group(1))
                    : new Locale(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(3))
                : new Locale(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(3),
                             matcher.group(5))
            : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would store instead a string concatenation of `Locale.getISO3Language()`, `getISO3Country()` and getVariant() as key, which would allow me to latter call `Locale(String language, String country, String variant)` constructor.

indeed, relying of displayLanguage implies using the langage of locale to display it, which make it locale dependant, contrary to iso language code.

As an example, en locale key would be storable as

```
en_EN
en_US
```

and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

Because I have just implemented it:

In `Groovy`/`Grails` it would be:

```
def locale = Locale.getAvailableLocales().find { availableLocale ->
      return availableLocale.toString().equals(searchedLocale)
}
```