# How to get iso2 language code for locale?

Tags: java, locale

I'm getting the iso2 language code this way:

```
public String getLang(Locale language)
    return language.toString().substring(0,2).toLowerCase()
}
```

Is there better way to do this?

**edit**: when i use getLanguage, i get an empty string.

Comment: Your method is not safe. E.g. The ISO3 code for Aragonese is `arg` while the ISO2 code is `an`.

Answer (score 14):

What about

```
public String getLang(Locale language)
    return language.getLanguage();
}
```

Of course, this will only be a iso 639-1 2-lettercode if there is one defined for this language, otherwise it may return a 3-letter code (or even longer).

---

Your code will give silly results if you have a locale without language code (like `_DE`) (mine will then return the empty string, which is a bit better, IMHO). If the locale contains a language code, it will return it, but then you don't need the `toLowerCase()` call.

Comment: For me this returns "nl_be", instead of the expected "nl". How is this possible? I had to use locale.getLanguage().split("_")[0] to get it :(

Comment: This does not work. Need to split the string. At least with Java 8

Answer (score 9):

I had the same questions and this is what I found.

If you create the `Locale` with the constructor as:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
```

and then you call `getLanguage`:

```
String language = locale.getLanguage();
```

The value of `language` will be "en_us";

If you create the `Locale` with the builder:

```
Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("US").build()
```

**Then the value `locale.getLanguage()` will return "en".**

This is strange to me but it's the way it was implemented.

So this was the long answer to explain that **if you want the language code to return a two-letter ISO language you need to use the Java `Locale` builder or do some string manipulation.**

Your method with `substring` works but I would use something like I wrote below to cover instances where the delimiter may be "-" or "_".

```
public String getLang(Locale language)
    String[] localeStrings = (language.split("[-_]+"));
    return localeStrings[0];
}
```

Comment: The issue here is that the constructor you are using is not parsing the code, but setting it as the "language" value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522248/how-to-get-locale-from-its-string-representation-in-java for how to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by calling [`Locale#getLanguage()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getLanguage%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

`Locale locale = ?; locale.getLanguage();`

Answer (score 1):

What about using the `toLanguageTag()` method?

Example:

```
public String getLang(Locale language) {
    return language.toLanguageTag();
}
```