# Freemarker - how to get the locale instance?

Tags: freemarker

From documentation special variable `.locale` retrieves a String representation of the locale.

But how can the `Locale` be retrieved within freemarker markup?

*If there is no built-in function I must pass the `Locale` to the template and pass it to each macro.*

Simplified example:

**Java Bean.class**

```
public Locale getLocale();
public String getFoo(Locale locale);
```

**Freemarker**

Cannot use string locale!

```
<#setting locale="${bean.getLocale()}"> 
${bean.getFoo(.locale)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `.locale_object` in 2.3.21 for that (should be released on 2014-10-12).

Otherwise, if you have put the `Locale` into the data-model, why would you need to pass that to each macro? Macros see the data-model variables.

Comment: good news :) Sorry i did not added it to the data-mode. Just setted it at the top of the markup.

Comment: Macros can see that variable too. Even if you are using `#import`-s and thus multiple namespaces, you can use `<#global myVar = myValue>`.

Comment: Updated to new version and good to know global variable feature, Freemarker is very powerful!

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker's .locale is a String not a Locale.

Not sure what your getFoo() is doing, but maybe you need a Locale in there? This answer will help you build it if you need that: [How to get Locale from its String representation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522248/how-to-get-locale-from-its-string-representation-in-java)